# How to use Jenkins for SPFx deployment?

Tags: spfx

I am learning SPFx development, I have deployed node applications using Jenkins. Similarly I am planning to deploy SPFx using Jenkins.
I tried to search for it but I never found good  article about deploy SPFx webpart using Jenkins.

My question is

1. Is it best practices to deploy SPFx webpart using Jenkins?
2. How can we use Jenkins as CI CD for SPFx? (Any reference article will be helpful)

Answer (score 0):

1. No. People usually do it with azuredevops
2. https://medium.com/@sekhar225/jenkins-for-spfx-951c979d706d

People usually do it with powershell or azure devops, if you have access to deploy the webpart from powershell I believe you can try to use the article above. If not you can write yourself a pipeline that can open puppeteer and do it "manually"